# How do you entertain a 7 week old infant?

Tags: newborn

I have a 7 week old baby and I stay home with him. The days can be long. I run out of ideas of how to entertain him. He doesn't talk or walk or crawl. He can't hold any toys. I don't want to always lie him on his back because of fear of a flat head but dont want to carry him. Also I feel that he isn't stimulated enough if I lay him down while I do other things. Please help.

Comment: You won't always have the time to be right there all day.  He might as well get used to finding his own ways of amusing himself.

Comment: I would encourage you to stay away from always entertaining him. They may grow to depend on it instead of experiencing things themselves. I would suggest a book called The Baby Whisperer. She goes through many things, but your fears will be covered.

Answer (score 5):

Everything is new for a small baby and everything is stimulating as they discover the environment around them. Change in lighting, a new sound or a colorful object can evoke a response. What cause it doesn't matter as it's all new.

Once they can hold their head up consider getting a chair so they can watch you. Move the chair around the house following you. If they don't like sitting for long periods maybe get a sling. Slings can be very comforting, especially as it's close, warm and they can hear your voice. Perfect for a sleep or watching and listening as you carry on.

Regarding slings, I recommend you find a group that can advise you on correct usage and positioning of your child especially the 'M' position. In the UK for example: https://www.nct.org.uk/parenting/sling-safety

Answer (score 3):

As a father of a 15 days old child. The below list helps

1. Sing to him - He knows he is around someone who keeps him comfortable.
2. Hold him close to you.
3. Walk him around the house
4. Talk to him while he stares at the lights. Talk to him and he does make eye contact.
5. Swaddle him - Some babies like to be swaddled.
6. Play white noises - Newborns like white noises
7. Try different holds - see what makes him comfortable.
8. Rocking motion on your arms.

While he certainly does not care for toys, but what matters to him is a feeling of being loved.

Comment: I like this - except I wouldn't recommend white noise specifically. Yes, the noise of the vacuum can be restful, but for the sake of the parent, also try music, bird or animal sounds, any noises in fact.

Answer (score 1):

You don't do much...

If you fear Flat Head that much, you should buy a helmet. Else, just let your kid sleep and rest on his own, somewhere where you can see him and where he can see you. You don't hold your kid when you sleep. It's the same when you are awake. You might want to find some soft support to put him. (We use babymove's doomoo but there should be a lot of possibilities.)

As for entertainment, at his age there is not a lot to do : your kids has to get through some developmental stages before really interacting with his environment. From personal experience, a house pet will do better than most toys to help your kid stimulate himself. Not that we let the cats raise our daughter ! But when she is playing on her mat, she tends to stop whatever she is doing as soon as one of them come close. Sometime, when she is crying, if one of them arrives to her before us, it'll be enough to calm her (works like a charm during naps).

Above all, don't cut yourself from life and don't over stress : a happy, caring, parent will have a happier baby.
And a sign you might be a good parent (I don't know you and thus can't judge) : you ask yourself if you are doing well and enough.
Once your kid starts to recognize you and is able to start expressing himself, the smiles will be indication enough of your results.